# in python what is the difference between map(func,list) and [func(x) for x in list]

Tags: dictionary, python

As far as I can tell the only difference is speed and you have to be a bit tricker in how you define lambda functions.

For instance:

```
map(lambda x: x + 1, range(4)) == [(lambda x: x + 1)(y) for y in range(4)]
```

It seems to me like the second way is more pythonic, but I am not sure why.

EDIT:

Yes I understand that the lambda would be excluded in the second example, I was just trying to show as equivalent code as possible.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map

Answer (score 6):

The right way to do this would be

```
[y + 1 for y in range(4)]
```

No need to construct a `lambda` function here.  Your code would unnecessarily build a new function object in every single iteration of the list comprehension.

That said, you can write any call to `map()` as an equivalent list comprehension.  If the first argument to `map()` is a `lambda` function, the list comprehension is usually preferred.  If the first argument to `map()` is a function name, both variants are fine.  Some people (including me) prefer, say,

```
map(str, my_list)
```

while others prefer

```
[str(x) for x in my_list]
```

Comment: Though if you were adding on some conditionals, the map would then need a lambda, right? `[y + 1 for y in range(4) if y > 2]`

Comment: @jdi: The call to `map()` always needs a `lambda` function for this case, doesn't it?  (Unless you resort to obfuscated code like `map(1 .__add__, range(4))`, that is.)

Comment: @SvenMarnach That wouldn't be syntactically valid (you need brackets), but I think that is kind of a nice way of expressing that.

Comment: @Marcin: This runs in my interpreter. (Note the space after `1` which is indeed needed.)

Comment: I think I was just mixing up various parts of your answer in my head lol. It was the 'no need for a lambda' part mixed with anything that can be written with a map can also be written with a list comp. So I was just commenting on the equivalent map for that list comp needing a lamba as opposed to an existing named callable or something. Im babbling.

Comment: `map` is especially nice when you want to call a function that takes multiple arguments.  I prefer `map(func, a, b)` to `[func(*args) for args in zip(a, b)]`

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference, but the pythonic way would be to omit the lambda completely:

```
[y + 1 for y in range(4)]
```

Note also that if your mapping function is a "built-in" (written in C) function, rather than a python function or a lambda, `map` will be faster.

Another pythonic, but uncommon, way (avoids unnecessary lambda) would be:

```
map(1 .__add__, range(4)) # thanks to SvenMarnach for this
```

It is usually preferable to avoid lambdas in mapping forms, because a list comprehension will always be more efficient, AND clearer. By contrast, using multi-line functions is perfectly acceptable - there is no way to write them inline, and even if you could, it would likely be less clear.

Another difference is that because `map` can take multiple sequences to map against, and passes them as positional parameters to the mapping function, one can avoid the zipping that would be required in a list comprehension:

```
[x+y for x,y in zip(range(4), range(2,6))]
#vs
from operator import add
map(add, range(4), range(2,6))
```

Comment: As a side note, in python 3 maps will create iterators and not lists, so be careful of that as you move forward with the language.

Comment: *"`map` may be microscopically faster in some cases (when you're NOT making a lambda for the purpose, but using the same function in map and a listcomp). List comprehensions may be faster in other cases [...]"* - from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1247490/1132524)

Comment: @RikPoggi True, but only in the case of built-in functions. Python functions all suffer from the same performance hit.

Comment: is "map(1 .__add__, range(4))" truly pythonic?

Comment: @placeybordeaux It's concise, explicit, and comprehensible